# FB.AppEvents.LogEvent for Facebook Canvas app

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

We have implemented Facebook SDK for our Unity app on iOS, Android and Facebook canvas app and want to use the FB.AppEvents.LogEvent method for analyzing in game events. For iOS and Android it works fine. But for Facebook canvas app with Unity binary it doesn't work. We find out that the following description of FB.AppEvents.LogEvent:
"Publish an app event, for deeper integration with Mobile App Install Ads. Mobile only, versions 4.3.3 and above."

Do we understand that the FB.AppEvents.LogEvent is actually for iOS and Android and can't use for Facebook app? If so then is there any substitute of FB.AppEvents.LogEvent for Facebook canvas apps?

Tanks a lot for any answers.

Comment: +1 seems silly if you can log events like "gained level" for iOS and Android, but not Canvas.